# Vue-router replace não funcionando?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rotas, pwa, vue-router

Estou desenvolvendo um PWA e estou com problemas no router, pois quando eu uso o botão voltar do meu smartphone ele percorre todas as rotas visitadas anteriormente para somente depois sair da aplicação, sendo que eu quero que quando o usuário use o botão de voltar na primeira vez, no máximo no segundo click ele feche a aplicação.

Já configurei algumas coisas no `beforeEach` do router:

```
export default (to, from, next) => {
  if (//verifica se o usuario está logado, caso não, encaminha para o login) {
    next('/login')
  }
  else {
    next({replace: true})
  }
}
```

E todas as vezes que chamo o router para redirecionar para alguma página ou rota diferente ao invés de usar `router.push(rota)` estou usando `router.replace(rota)`

Já verifiquei todos os lugares onde usa o router e em todos eles configurei para usar o `replace()` ao invés do `push()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu `beforeEach` não está correto. Ele deve estar no mesmo escopo onde está instanciado seu `router`.

```
const router = new VueRouter({ ... })

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // ...
})
```